# confusion with XPath number() function

Tags: xpath

I was reading the document of [`XPath Number function`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Number-Functions).

> The number function should not be used for ***conversion of numeric data occurring in an element in an XML document unless the element is of a type that represents numeric data in a language-neutral format*** (which would typically be transformed into a language-specific format for presentation to a user). In addition, ***the number function cannot be used unless the language-neutral format used by the element is consistent*** with the XPath syntax for a Number.
>
> ***an object of a type other than the four basic types is converted to a number in a way that is dependent on that type***

Can anyone point me what the above bold line meant technically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that number() can't handle strings that represent numbers in locale-dependent formats such as 1'000'000. If it sounds unnecessarily complicated, that's probably because the working group had an intense debate about whether or not number() should handle localized numbers, decided it shouldn't, and left this text in the spec as fossil evidence of their deliberations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also tried to test `boolean true is converted to 1; boolean false is converted to 0`(taken from the same link). But I got error. What does they mean by the sentence?

Comment: It means that the result of number(2=2) is 1, and the result of number(2=3) is 0.

Comment: That completely understood, what I mean to say in case of XML node, how this would be fit?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

This means the method cannot be used to convert localized numerical strings to number, like:

```
1.200,20
```

which is a german number format. Only numerical strings like defined in the [XPath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-Number) lead to reliable results. So the number above will have to look like:

```
1200.20
```